# Add Formdata(File) from drag and drop to a physical form element

Tags: javascript, forms, drag-and-drop, form-data

**Now it is true that this question is really new and has not been asked anywhere as i have done some digging....**
However i have managed to grab the files from the drag and drop interface but then again i would like to add those files to the **physical form Element** in order to make it easy to to code for the progress bars and other events targeting only one form but not a double form submittion.
What i have managed to do as of now is to **submit the physical form on its own** when the user selects files,,,, and s**ubmit the drag and drop javascript formdata object on its own as well**, so they are very different and i need to code for more even which in this case will mean more code required!
somebody please help me...